# how do I call class object as a method parameter

Tags: java

I have 3 classes, one is Account, one is Bank and one is Main. In the bank class I have a method

```
public boolean addAccount(Account account){
return false;}
```

I have some code in this method, my question is how do I call this method from the class with the main method??? My parameter is the class but it is from another class I can't find an example of this.

I have tried creating an object but it does not work for example if I do

```
Account someObject = new Account(); or
Bank someObject = new Bank();
```

it is not going to allow me to access both classes right? Sorry I just don't get it...

The point of this is to add a new account and later on with a different method check the account. I already have some account objects with the name of account, the number of the account and the balance. Any help clarifying this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't call an instance method without an instance. Either create an instance, or make the method static.

Comment: "it is not going to allow me to access both classes right? ". Is there any error coming?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example will help:

```
class ObjectPassDemo 
{ 
    int a, b; 

    ObjectPassDemo(int i, int j) 
    { 
        a = i; 
        b = j; 
    } 


    boolean equalTo(ObjectPassDemo o) 
    { 
        return (o.a == a && o.b == b); 
    } 
} 


public class Test 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        ObjectPassDemo ob1 = new ObjectPassDemo(100, 22); 
        ObjectPassDemo ob2 = new ObjectPassDemo(100, 22); 
        ObjectPassDemo ob3 = new ObjectPassDemo(-1, -1); 

        System.out.println("ob1 == ob2: " + ob1.equalTo(ob2)); 
        System.out.println("ob1 == ob3: " + ob1.equalTo(ob3)); 
    } 
}
```

Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org

Answer (score 0):

You call such a method with the syntax:

```
someBankObject.addAccount(someAccountObject);
```

Depending on the code you already have it might look like this:

```
Account johnDoeAccount = new Account("John", "Doe", "JD-423-127-231"); // example
Bank centralBank = new Bank();
centralBank.addAccount(johnDoeAccount);
```

Now your `account` variable inside your `addAccount()` method will reference the account from John Doe.

Comment: Thank you everyone it all makes sense now :)